# conversion of Date : issue in IE

Tags: date, internet-explorer-11, momentjs

I have a date in following format..

**"Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016"**

Whenever i am trying to convert this date in 
**new Date("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016")** it is giving me an error says invalid date and i also tried **moment("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016") and moment(new Date("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016"))** it is giving the same error as invalid date in IE.

This issue is only in IE, in chrome it is working fine. I want the result in this format moment("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `Date` object for its parsing abilities.  You will find the implementations vary considerably across browsers.  You're already using moment.js, so use its parser instead.  You will have to be explicit about the input format.

```
var m = moment("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016", "ddd MMM D H:mm:ss ZZ YYYY");
```

You can then format it however you like by passing a different format to the `format` function.

Also note that by default, moment will convert the above to the user's local time zone.  If that's not what you intended, then consider using `moment.parseZone` instead.  Refer [to the user guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/), and also to [this blog article](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/).